# Databricks fails to create StructType / Schema when used against case class installed as Jar file

Tags: scala, apache-spark, databricks, azure-databricks

I am using ScalaReflection to create schema from Case Classes. I have installed the jar containing the case classes in the databricks cluster and When I invoke the following command
`ScalaReflection.schemaFor[TESTCaseClass].dataType.asInstanceOf[StructType]`
I get the following error
`AnnotationFormatError: Duplicate annotation for class: interface scala.reflect.ScalaLongSignature: @scala.reflect.ScalaLongSignature`

Below is the code that I am doing

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType 
case class TEST(
                 VAR1: String,
                 VAR2: String
               )
def TestSchema: StructType = ScalaReflection.schemaFor[TEST].dataType.asInstanceOf[StructType]
```

> Scala version : 2.12.10
> Spark Version : 3.1.1
> Databricks cluster runtime : 8.3

I compile the class to .class file and it fails in databricks while invoking from databricks cell with following error

```
AnnotationFormatError: Duplicate annotation for class: interface scala.reflect.ScalaLongSignature: @scala.reflect.ScalaLongSignature
```